# How Can I Reduce The Default Time of The Scheduled Interval of the Background Agent in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: .net, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, background-agents

I have an issue with the periodic task of the background agent in windows phone 8.

I want to reduce the default Time(30 Mins) of  the Scheduled Interval.

How can i make that ?!!

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You cannot Reduce that on Windows phone 8. May I ask you what are you trying to achieve ? If there is no other solution, consider going to Windows Phone 8.1 where you have a lot more possibilities with "Background Agents".

Comment: i want it to check for a condition every five minutes even if the app is closed , and if so , i want to notify the user .

Comment: Then as I said before, you should go with Windows Phone 8.1. In windows phone 8, The 30 minute periodic agent is the best you can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not. The OS will run the task whenever it'll think it's runnable ( e.g. Not in power saver ). Even you can not be sure it'll runn at all.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to configure the period. What you can do is - write the last time the agent ran into a file. When the agent runs again, check the file to decide whether you should just exit or do the desired work.